# Comparing two Sybase databases

Tags: sybase

Sybase server of my product is going to be upgraded from version 12 to 15.

I am looking for a script to take a snapshot of the server before upgrade and then after upgrade, with an aim to quickly compare and assure myself that all the tables / indices / views / stored procs / users and permissions are there.

I am a dev (and not a DBA) and I will have only a command line access to production server (which is a Solaris box).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

A really low tech answer, but this should work. Get the following information from both the Sybase servers and check that they match. A quick CSV compare, maybe?

```
-- Compare name of all tables, views and triggers. 
SELECT ob.name, ob.type FROM sysobjects ob WHERE ob.type in ('U', 'V', 'TR') ORDER BY ob.name

-- Compare name of stored procs
SELECT ob.name FROM sysobjects ob WHERE ob.type ="P" ORDER BY ob.name

-- Compare list of all columns of all table and views. 
select ob.name, c.name, c.type, c.length, c.prec, c.scale
from sysobjects ob, syscolumns c
where ob.type in ('U','V') and ob.id=c.id
order by ob.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view on sysobjects like this: CREATE VIEW myview as SELECT name, user_name(uid) as objectowner, type from sysobjects order by 1,2,3
Then do a BCP-out from the view:

bcp yourdb..myview out myfile.txt -Usa -Pyourpaswd -SYOURSERVER -c

Do this before and after the upgrade and do a 'diff' between the files.